# PowerApp UI is different in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

This the PowerApp UI which I want to add in sharePoint using powerApp webpart
[image]

But when I added this UI in sharePoint, the view is different. I'm not able to see the Edit form in right side or the icons. Only the gallery in left side is visible in sharePoint
[image]

Comment: Did you publish the latest version of Power Apps?

Comment: Yes. When I tried with mobile orientation UI, it works fine. I don't know what's wrong with the browser orientation.